# golang gorm update associations on save

Tags: go, go-gorm

is there a way to automatically remove associations when an object is saved?

something like this:

```
type Parent struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Children []*Child
}

type Child struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    ParentID uint
}

func myFunc(db *gorm.DB) {
    p := &Parent{Name: "foo", Children:[]*Child{ {Name:"Bar"}, {Name:"Foobar"}}}
    db.Save(&p)

    p.Children = p.Children[1:]
    db.Save(&p)  // both children still exist in the database. i'd like the first child to be deleted here
}
```

`

I've found some tricks with db.Model(&Parent).Association("Children").Clear(), but that just sets the ParentID value to NULL, rather than deleting the record. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer ? I'm facing the same issue here...

Comment: yes it's possible to remove the child using its maping key value

Comment: @muthukumarselvaraj how would you do that? Could you post it as an answer. The current answer only hard deletes instead of soft delete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just simply use the physical batch delete like following code:

```
db.Unscoped().Where("parent_id = ?", p.ID).Delete(Child{})
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This will hard delete the records